# how to use the formula in picture for matlab?

Tags: density-function

[![the picture is pdf and realibility formula]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/df3Nc.jpg)how to use the formula in picture for matlab?
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/df3Nc.jpg)